# Print only lines with highest value

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, sort

I need to process a file like below in the bash script:

**input.txt:**

```
host1 53
host1 123
host2 0
host1 222
host3 1
host1 85
host1 25
host1 13
host3 8
host2 90
```

I need to get in the results only one line for each host based on maximum
value in column 2:

**output.txt:**

```
host1 222
host2 90
host3 8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So what did you try? It is quite easy in awk :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `sort` or compatible:

```bash
<input.txt sort -k2rn | sort -sbuk1,1 >output.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

The shortest one with GNU **`datamash`**:

```
datamash -sW -g1 max 2 <file
```

- `-s` - sort the input before grouping
- `-W` - use whitespace (one or more spaces and/or tabs) for field delimiters
- `-g 1` - group via 1st field
- `max 2` - numeric operation to get the maximum value of the 2nd field per group

---

The output:

```
host1   222
host2   90
host3   8
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the awk one-liner:

```
$ awk '{if (a[$1] == "" || $2 > a[$1]) a[$1] = $2} END { for (k in a) print k, a[k] }' < input.txt
host1 222
host2 90
host3 8
```

`$1` and `$2` are the first two fields of the line, associative array `a[k]` holds the current maximum for key `k`. With the test against `a[$1]` being empty, it should deal with negative numbers correctly.